# query to select data between todays date as well as tomorrows date time upto specific time

Tags: mysql, php

I have database "raj" with table "pagination"

In table pagination have "id", "actualtime" and "created" field

```
id - auto_increment
name- varchar
created- datetime
```

I want to **display all rows which is created on todays date display upto yesterdays 06:00 pm.after that the content will be refreshed based on based on a DATETIME field called 'created'** that holds the date and time of each record's creation.

this is my query to fetch rows but it is not working properly...plz help me......

```
$sql = "
    SELECT name 
    FROM pagination where created >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
       ";
```

Comment: And how is it not working properly? Does it generate an error? Does it return results that you are not expecting?

Comment: yes it does not return expected result...

Comment: i need a query to display data from today date till 06:00 pm yesterday.... after that the content will be refreshed.plz help me....

Answer (score 2):

This is the expression for 6:00 PM yesterday

```
SELECT DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 HOUR;
```

Craft the SELECT with that expression

```
SELECT * FROM pagination WHERE
created >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 HOUR;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

Default `current_Date` or `curdate` gives the date as if `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00`, making the time as PM will help your query

```
SELECT name
FROM pagination 
WHERE created >= DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 18 HOUR),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```