# select value between particular date and time schedule

Tags: mysql, php

I have database "raj" with table "pagination"

In table pagination have "id", "actualtime" and "created" field

id - auto_increment actualtime- varchar created- datetime

that looks like this
CREATE TABLE pagination(
    id int auto_increment,
    actualtime varchar(55),
    created datetime
)

I want to display all rows which are created on todays date and will display from today upto yesterday at 06:00 pm. 
after that the content will be refreshed based on based on a DATETIME field called 'created' that holds the date and time of each record's creation.

**this is my query to fetch rows but it display value after 06:00 pm on yesterday but i want to display all data before 06:00 pm from currentdate.  After 06:00 pm data will be refreshed and clear. plz help me......**

SELECT actualtime 
FROM pagination 
WHERE created BETWEEN date_add(date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 day), INTERVAL 18 hour) AND curdate()";

Comment: plz suggest the answer.....

Comment: The same question has been answered at 

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76205/query-to-select-data-between-todays-date-as-well-as-tomorrows-date-time-upto-spe/76224#76224